# aria-expanded in a <div> element

Tags: html, accessibility

I made this dropdown menu. The problem is that it is not accessible because `aria-expanded` is used on a div element. Unfortunately it is not possible for me to remove the aria-expanded attribute as it determines the functioning of the accordion. Is it possible to make another solution or add another attribute that solves the problem?

[image: menu]

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Add HTML to your post.

Comment: If you want your menu to be accessible you _must_ remove the inappropriate use of any ARIA attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible for me to remove the aria-expanded attribute as it determines the functioning of the accordion. ==> That accordion component isn't accessible at present. Fix it yourself, or take another component. Please post code if you need help to fix it.

Comment: the point is that most assistive technologies will ignore `aria-expanded` on a `div`, as it's not suppoed to be used on a non-interactive element. As Quentin says, we need to see your HTML code if we're to advise you properly on what to change, but I would assume that rather than have a click event on a div, you have the chevrons be HTML `button`s and make the click to expand/contract apply only to those - and then add `aria-expanded` to those buttons.

Comment: In fact the latest ARIA specification makes it clear that [aria-expanded is only supposed to be used on elements of particular roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-expanded) (see table and the "used in roles" section). A `div` by default has none of these roles (you could give it `role="button"` but that will cause other issues, assuming those radio buttons are inside the div, because you shouldn't nest interactive elements).